# Add column to SQL table and populate to datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a windows form application with databound datagridview. I want to add column at run time (if user wants to add more column to it). So on button click I wanted to add column. I have added following code to event it adds column in server explorer view under tables column's list but does not show in table definition neither in data source window (in column list under table) nor in datagridview.

```
 Imports System.Configuration
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient

 Public Class Form3
     Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Small_databaseDataSet.newtable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
       Me.NewtableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Small_databaseDataSet.newtable)

     End Sub

     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddColumn()
     End Sub

     Private Sub AddColumn()
          Dim connString As String = "Data Source=(localDb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=small database;Integrated Security=True"
          Dim dt As New DataTable

          Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)

              Dim str As String = "ALTER TABLE newtable ADD " & TextBoxX1.Text & " INT null;"
              Using comm As New SqlCommand(str, conn)
              conn.Open()
              comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
          End Using

        End Using

        Validate()
        DataGridViewX1.Columns.Clear()
        NewtableTableAdapter.Update(Small_databaseDataSet.newtable)
        NewtableTableAdapter.Fill(Small_databaseDataSet.newtable)
        DataGridViewX1.DataSource = NewtableBindingSource

  End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
' Add the keyword NULL and brackets around the column name
Dim comm As New SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE testTable ADD [col1] INT NULL", conn)
```

If I wanted to have the new column to show up automatically, I would re-query the database, retrieving the data on that table and just set the datagridview datasource to the resultset like:

```
'I assume the datagridview name is DataGridView1
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
DataGridView1.DataSource = USTDatabaseDataSet
DataGridView1.DataMember = "testTable" 
DataGridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: I tried re - querying, Still Its not showing in on datagridview and data source window and in table definition as well. I can only see in server explorer's window only.

Comment: but just check when I delete table from data source and add it again though configuration wizard, it does show in data source window but still not in datagridview

Comment: Hmmmm ... sounds like maybe the datagridview columns are still set from the previous bind, try clearing the columns definition (`DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()`) and then re-bind.  I edited my answer to include the code.

Comment: I did added that line too. but dont know why its still not working. I have edited my recent code in question could you please have a look and direct me?

Answer (score 0):

A DataReader is used to retrieve data. Since there is no data retrieved nothing is loaded into your DataTable except maybe a return value of success or failure. The Using statements ensure that your objects are closed and disposed properly even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub AddColumn()
        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("USTDatabaseConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Using comm As New SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE testTable ADD col1 INT;", conn)
                conn.Open()
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            Using com2 As New SqlCommand("Select * From testTable;", conn)
                Using reader As SqlDataReader = com2.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(reader)
                    conn.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
```

Comment: Still Its not showing in on datagridview and data source window and in table defination as well. I can only see in server explorer's window only.

Comment: Just tested and it works fine for me. Are you scrolling all the way to the right to see the new column? Does nothing show in the grid? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Once the column exists, if you try to add it again you will get an error and the select portion of the code will not run. Remove the 4 lines of code which add the column and try it.

Comment: I am passing variable with different column name each time but still not working. it gives me error if i add same name to textbox so that part is working . i think it just me not refreshing it correectly to show up in datasource window and datagridview